# SQL - Find all "Relationship IDs" where key equals value, then select all records containing those "Relationship IDs"

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have a huge painful inherited table of a few million records I am having trouble querying efficiently. The table looks a little like this:

```
id | submissionId | key     | value
------------------------------------
1  | 1            | userID  | 1
2  | 1            | data    | stuff
3  | 2            | userID  | 2
4  | 2            | data    | stuff2
5  | 2            | data2   | stuff3
6  | 3            | userID  | 1
7  | 3            | data    | stuff2
8  | 3            | data2   | stuff3
```

What I am trying to query is select all "submission data" for a particular user. So the result for `userID === 1` would only select userID related "submission data" ie:

```
1  | 1            | userID  | 1
2  | 1            | data    | stuff
6  | 3            | userID  | 1
7  | 3            | data    | stuff2
8  | 3            | data2   | stuff3
```

At the moment my best solution is selecting all records for a specific userID. Then looping through the results and putting the submissionID's into an array. Then selecting all records where the submissionID matches a  submissionID in my array.

This becomes hugely time consuming as there are around 15,000 users which need to be looped through as well. Any ideas to make this more efficient or in a single query would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Don't tag products not directly involved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply query for any record which has a `submissionId` related to a particular `value`:

```
SELECT *
FROM submissions
WHERE submissionId IN (SELECT submissionId
                       FROM submissions
                       WHERE value = 1 AND key = 'userID')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable AS t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM mytable AS t2
              WHERE t2.submissionId = t1.submissionId AND
                    t2.key = 'userID' AND t2.value = 1)
```